# Symfony - argument is type-hinted "array" you should configure its value explicitly

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

In my `Symfony 5.4` I get an error:

> Cannot autowire service "App\Core\Shared\Query\CollectionQueryFactory": argument "$collectionOptions" of method "__construct()" is type-hinted "array", you should configure its value explicitly.

I wanted to explicitly configure what Symfony DI should pass. Tried with tagged iterator.

```
class CollectionQueryFactory implements CollectionQueryFactoryInterface
{
    private array $collectionOptions;

    public function __construct(array $collectionOptions)
    {
        $this->collectionOptions = $collectionOptions;
    }

    ...
```

And in my `services.yaml` file:

```
    App\Core\Shared\Query\CollectionQueryFactory:
      arguments:
        $collectionOptions: '%api_platform.collection.pagination%'
```

Comment: It is an Api Platform pagination class. @IMSoP

Comment: It is: return \array_merge([
   'page_parameter_name' => 'page',
   'items_per_page_parameter_name' => 'itemsPerPage',
  ], $this->collectionOptions);

@IMSoP

Comment: I'm not clear how that line of code relates to what you put in the question. Can you [edit] to show some more of the relevant configuration and code? At the moment, there seem to be a lot of assumptions in the question.

Comment: What I am trying to tell it that it is configured "explicitly" in services.yaml file.. So I do not know what can be an issue here? @IMSoP

Comment: Well, clearly _something_ is not working how you expected, so in order to debug it, you need to find all the pieces of code that might be relevant; and in order for _someone with no access to your code_ to debug it, you need to _show_ all those pieces of code.

Comment: Just for fun, replace `'%api_platform.collection.pagination%'` with an ordinary array just to see if the error goes away.  Though from what you posted, even if what you are passing is not an array you would have gotten a different error message.  Double check your spelling in services.yaml and maybe try to ensure you don't have a compiler pass or something trying to make it's own service definition.

Comment: Thanks for this proposal. I tried with that and I got the same message as before, which is odd. @Cerad

Answer (score 0):

if `api_platform.collection.pagination` is definitely a normal PHP array, then if you change it in the constructor to `array $collectionOptions = []` it should then auto-wire correctly